# Discard a messed up git fork in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution, git-fork

For development purposes, I work with a fork of the main project. Every now and again, I pull in the parent repo:

```
git fetch parent
git merge parent/master
```

On this occasion, there had been a lot of work done by others, so when I did that, I pulled in 147 commits, so `git status` showed that I was well ahead of `origin` (my fork). I did a bit of work. I had made five commits, but I wanted to squash the last two into one commit. The usual trick here is to do `git rebase -i`, and then edit the last message to `squash`. I did this.

When I saw how massive the list was, I exited without saving changes. Squashing the two commits into one wasn't really that important, so I abandoned the idea. However, git still ran through the list of commits, redoing all of them, which took a long while.

When I pushed, and then opened a pull request on Bitbucket, Bitbucket tried to apply *all* of the commits, not just the ones I'd done myself. And since other changes had been made since, this resulted in a bunch of merge conflicts in code I hadn't touched.

Is there any neat way to resolve this? I'm thinking of nuking my fork and reforking (none of my branches contain anything valuable), but perhaps there's something less destructive I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just nuke individual branches in your fork and reset them to where the parent is:

```
git fetch parent
git checkout master
git reset --hard parent/master
git push -f
```

That way, you will still have the few commits you want to keep, and you'll be able to cherry-pick them afterwards, via branches they are on or via the reflog.

Comment: It worked! To check, I opened a new pull request and was told that there are no changes, so a pull request cannot be created.